# delete rows from tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I have a scenario where in one view i display list of records in a table and on clicking accessory button user navigates to details screen on which i have approve and reject button .
I want to delete records from the table in main view when user taps approve / reject button in the details view .
Below code can be used when i want to delete records from same view

```
    [self.appDelegate.actualPOList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Please help me on this , how can this be achieved .

Thanks .

Comment: Yeah, you should delete the rows from the data structure that the view is a representation of, then you can reload the table as mentioned in the the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

1) You just have to modify your model.

You can use your current call: `[self.appDelegate.actualPOList removeObjectAtIndex: index];`;
You could save the index as tag of your detailviewcontroller's view.

2) Than you do a reload in your table, when it is appearing again.

```
- (void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

send ur indexpath to your detail view like create detailview controller and store indexpath.row into nsinteger which is created in detail controller like on didselect row function in tableview controller
 mydetailcontroller *obj=[[mydetailcontroler alloc]init];

```
obj.my_index=indexpath.row;
```

self.navigationcontroller pushviewcontroller;
 in detail controller

[self.appDelegate.actualPOList removeObjectAtIndex:my_index;
and in viewwillappear of tableviewcontroller 
[self.tableview reloaddata]